# C++ threads not running parallel on linux/mac os

Tags: c++11

I am using g++ compiler on linux(ubuntu on virtual box).  I am calling join properly on  std::threads after creation.  The do seem to start at once, but finishes one after another.  The total run time is n times single threaded time.  I do not see this problem with pthreads.  Pthreads scale perfectly and the run time is (1/n) times single threaded time.

Observed the same behavior with clang++ compiler on Mac OS.

Is it possible that std::thread's are run only at the time of 'join' is called?  Should i have to pass any additional parameters in std::thread constructor to force them to run in parallel?  Searched c++11 documentation and could not find any obvious reason.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The standard doesn't require that separate instances of `std::thread` run in parallel, only they they offer the _possibility_ of running in parallel. Try sleeping in the main thread and see what happens.

Comment: When are you calling `join()`? If you call it "after creation", you force calling thread to wait for newly created thread completion.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear. But to answer your question. Yes, it is possible that your thread runs when it is being called join. But it is very unlikely.

The function of join() returns when the thread execution has completed. If your function A() launches a function B() in a separate thread, and you join the thread in function A(), the execution of A() will be halted at the point of join until B() has finished its execution.

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/

> The function returns when the thread execution has completed.
>   This synchronizes the moment this function returns with the completion of all the operations in the thread: This blocks the execution of the thread that calls this function until the function called on construction returns (if it hasn't yet).

Another suggestion will be to check this will be to detach the processes and check if your are getting your result faster. This will help you identify the problem i.e. if join() is causing the issue.